# Using SED and/or AWK to replace line with pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed

This is the input file

```
def test():
    print('do something')
    #>#> this does something
    return 0

def new_test(arg):
    # >#>this too does something
    x = 0
    y = 1

    return x+y

def main():
    test()
    z = 'hello'
    # ># this should not work
    return null

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # >#> main call
    main()
```

the output should look like:

```
def test():
    print('do something')
    some_fn("this does something")
    return 0

def new_test(arg):
    some_fn("this too does something")
    x = 0
    y = 1

    return x+y

def main():
    test()
    z = 'hello'
    # ># this should not work
    return null

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_fn("main call")
    main()
```

I couldn't find a way to extract the comment string.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include non-trivial cases, e.g I assume you wouldn't want `print('#>#> this does something')` converted to `print(some_fn("this does something"))`. Or maybe you would, idk... The point is it's trivial to match the strings you want and much harder to not match similar-looking strings you don't want so before more people post answers that'll fail for the non-trivial cases and then we have to start peeling the onion to get to your real requirements, just take a few minutes now to really think about what you need and provide sample input/output to cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a standard `sed`, you'd go like this:

```
sed  's/# *>#> *\(.*\)/some_fn("\1")/' file
```

- Your `#>#>` pattern seems to allow some extra spaces, so I used `# *>#> *` as a pattern. Please adapt it, if other spaces are allowed.
- The `.*` matches the rest of the line. I placed it inside `\(\)`, so I can refer to it in the replacement as `\1`

Answer (score 0):

You can make short work of this using `GNU sed`and with the extended regex option, `-E`.

```
$ sed -Ee 's/^(\s+)#\s*>#>\s*(\S.*)/\1some_fn("\2")/' file
```

- ^(\s+) will remember the indent level
- #  and >#> are two strings that are optionally followed by spaces.
- (\S.*) stores the message portion
- then on the replacement portion we recall the indent level `\1`  and message `\2` and intersperse with the string some_fn

Or, with `awk`, we choose the field separator to be the regex `#\s*>#>\s*` so
then the indent level is `$1` while the
message is `$2`

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
      s = "[[:blank:]]*" 
      FS = "#" s ">#>" s
      OFS = ""; q = "\""
    }
    NF > 1 {
      $2 = "some_fn(" q$2q ")"
    }1
' file
```